# Partial rollback required in NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus, transactionscope

I have an odd scenario. I have an NServiceBus (v3) handler that processes updates to a business entity. When that entity is in a certain state, only part of that entity can be changed (a reference field to help with debugging) whilst the rest of the update is discarded and an error is then thrown.

Since the NSB handlers run in their own transaction scope, the thrown exception prevents the reference field update from being logged.

I thought I would be able to force a child `TransactionScope` but this just seems to lock up the database and results in a timeout exception in NServiceBus, specifically:

> Exception of type
>   'NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportMessageHandlingFailedException'
>   was thrown. **OriginalException:** Timeout expired.  The timeout period
>   elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not
>   responding.

Example code:

```
public class UpdateEntityHandler : HandlerBase, IHandleMessages<UpdateEntityMessage>
{
    public IEntityService EntityService { get; set; }

    public ILogService LogService { get; set; }

    public void Handle(UpdateEntityMessage message)
    {
        // get the entity
        var entity = this.EntityService.GetEntity(message.Id);

        // log the message (DTC coordinated)
        this.LogService.Log(message);

        // set the reference no
        entity.ReferenceNo = message.ReferenceNo;

        // if some odd condition then we need to exit
        if (entity.TypeId == (int)EntityType.ForceError)
        {
            // force this into it's own TransactionScope
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
            {
                // update need to be saved and not rolled back
                this.EntityService.Update(entity);
                scope.Complete();
            }

            // force the error to prevent 
            throw new ApplicationException("Error was forced");
        }

        // Set values
        entity.StatusId = (int)EntityStatus.Updated;
        entity.Balance = this.EntityService.SetBalance(entity, message);

        // update normally
        this.EntityService.Update(entity);
    }
```

I need to treat this condition as an exception (for other reasons), but I need some of the database updates not to be rolled back. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log the message in another transaction, then I would consider either doing a .SendLocal() to another handler that just does the logging, or using the audit feature to forward a copy of the message to another endpoint and do the logging there.  This will ensure your logging will always succeed, and the entity is free to roll back.

Update: Another possibility would be to use a custom fault handler to do the logging you need.

Comment: Does SendLocal() need any further configuration, or should it just work in a assembly that is configured AsA_Server? Also, I assume that the log message wouldn't be rolled back as well?

Comment: There is no further configuration required.  It will send to endpoints queue which is local and would not require a distributed transaction.  I have not tested if an exception occurs the audit feature fails.  I would think not, but I don't want to give a false answer.

Comment: Sent messages are rolled back as well.

Comment: @UdiDahan that was my fear. I think I need to think of another way around this.

Comment: My recommendation would be to move away from the use of exceptions.